# How to plot the eigenvalues of a parametric matrix efficiently?

Tags: performance-tuning, assumptions, eigenvalues

I was wondering how can I set the variable type of matrix elements to be real.
The problem is, I creat a variable-dependent matrix as follows
[image]

and I get the eigenvalues
[image]
now I want to plot the functions above.
The trouble is it cost a lot of time, and I don't know how to Compile such a set of function.
So my problem is that how can I set the variable type at the very first or use the "Compile" to set the set of eigenvalues to be real-number valued?
My code is listed in the following

```
L = 4;
H[t_] := SparseArray[
Flatten[
{
Table[{2 j - 1, 2 j} -> t, {j, 1, L}],
Table[{2 j, 2 j - 1} -> t, {j, 1, L}],
Table[{2 j, 2 j + 1} -> 1.0, {j, 1, L - 1}],
Table[{2 j + 1, 2 j} -> 1.0, {j, 1, L - 1}]
}
]
];
H[t] // MatrixForm
ev = Eigenvalues[H[t]]
Plot[ev, {t, -3.0, 3.0}]
```

**Update**:
Thank @Henrik Schumacher@Roman very much.

Something went wrong when I applied it to an asymmetric matrix.

```
L=40;
H[t_]:= SparseArray[
Flatten[
{
 Table[{2 j - 1, 2 j} -> t-2/3, {j, 1, L}],
 Table[{2 j, 2 j - 1} -> t+2/3, {j, 1, L}],
 Table[{2 j, 2 j + 1} -> 1.0, {j, 1, L - 1}],
 Table[{2 j + 1, 2 j} -> 1.0, {j, 1, L - 1}]
 }
]
];
H[t] // MatrixForm
```

Such a matrix have complex eigenvalues. And I will polt their real parts and imaginary parts separately.

```
f[t_?NumericQ]:= Re[Eigenvalues[H[N[t]]]]
Plot[Sort[f[t]], {t,-3.0,3.0}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It took me about 5min, and here's the result

[image]
[image]

The left part is quite regular but the right part in the red box is not as smooth as that of the left part. And I wonder what's wrong?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Even with real `t`, the eigenvalues are roots of a polynomial of degree `8`. There is just no general closed-form expression for polynomials of degree greater than 5.

Comment: I don't understand. Running your code (and generating the plot) takes about 3 seconds. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Hello@bill s^_^,I take L=4 as an example. In fact I will deal with L=40 or even larger, and plot the eigenvalues as functions of the parameter t. At that time such a procedure is time - consuming.

Comment: Try increasing `PlotPoints` to make it smoother

Comment: Hello@KraZug，thx for ur comment. It seems that 'plotpoints' is not the case, for a comparision the left part at the same place, is quite good.

Comment: Do you require that the eigenvalues are joined up, or just plotted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this helps? It shifts the computation to efficient eigenvalue computations in machine precision. The plot needs only 0.15 seconds on my machine.

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[H[N[t]]];
Plot[Sort[f[t]], {t, -3.0, 3.0}]
```

## Edit

As it turns out, you are lucky: For the characteristic polynomial of `H[t]` is a polynomial of order $L$ order in $t^2$. Thus, it can be solved explicitly for $L \leq 4$ and the result can be compiled:

```
H[t_, L_] := With[{a = Most[Join @@ ConstantArray[{t, 1}, L]]},
   SparseArray[{
     Band[{1, 2}] -> a,
     Band[{2, 1}] -> a
     },
    {2 L, 2 L}, 0
    ]
   ];
L =4;
cλ = With[{
    code = N[λ /.mSolve[Det[H[t, L] - λ IdentityMatrix[2 L]] == 0, λ]]
    },
   Compile[{{t, _Complex}},
    Re@code,
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];

a = -3.;
b = 3.;
ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[cλ[Subdivide[a, b, 1000]]], 
  DataRange -> {a, b}
  ]
```

[image]

However, this is limited to the case $L \leq  4$.

Comment: Hello @Henrik Schumacher,  I would like to thank you for your helpful advice very much. You have perfectly solved my problem. The reason why I would set the variable type to be real is that from my limited knowledge it would remarkably speed up the ploting of functions. I am a beginner of MMA and your method is fantastic, and I'm looking forward to learning form such expert as you in the future.

Comment: You are flattering me. Anyways, you're welcome.

Comment: `f[t_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[H[N[t]]]` for a speedup even if `t` is given as an infinite-precision object.

Comment: @Roman Good point. I relied on the fact that `Plot` supplies `f` only with machine precision numbers.